# Is $ p(a|b) \propto p(b|a) $ if $ p(a) $ is uniform? Why?

Tags: probability, bayesian

As the title says, is $ p(a|b) \propto p(b|a) $ if $ p(a) $ is uniform? Why?

Comment: Have you looked at Bayes' Theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Comment: By basics properties of probabilities $p(a \mid b) = \frac{p(b \mid a) p(a)}{p(b)}$. Since $p(a)$ is uniform it's basically a constant, let call it $c$, so that $p(a \mid b) =  \frac{p(b \mid a) \times c}{p(b)}$. The right hand side, as seen as a function of $a$, is then $\propto p(b \mid a)$

Comment: @periwinkle that looks like an answer to me!